# Setting status code of response has no effect on web api core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

AspNetCore 3.1.3

I'm trying to write a custom error result to return them consistently to the users whenever necessary.
I started by inheriting from `StatusCodeResult` and overriding the `ExecuteResult` method, like this:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
{
    base.ExecuteResult(context);
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ErrorMessage);
    context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Then I realized that the response body I was writing was completely ignored, and the response was

```
status: 422
title: "Unprocessable Entity"
traceId: "|5c53f94f-4826199e14151b80."
type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918#section-11.2"
```

Tried everything I could think of to change the body, but the framework just overwrites this automagically and I couldn't find information on where or how.

Then I proceeded to extend `IClientErrorActionResult`, imeplementing the interface like this:

```
public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ErrorMessage);
    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 422;
    await context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    await context.HttpContext.Response.CompleteAsync();
}
```

This time the body of the response matched whatever I wrote, but the `StatusCode` was always automagically changed to 200, even though I'm setting it to 422 before writing the response.

My question is: how can I change the body returned from `StatusCodeResult` or make the framework respect the `StatusCode` I'm setting inside my 'ExecuteResultAsync' method from `IActionResult`.

Also, if anyone could point me to any kind of documentation of what is going on here, where these overwrites are happening and why, I would appreciate it.